# Using scanf() delimiters not working as expected

Tags: c, format, scanf

I have a string input that goes like this

`string@floatValue`

A set of values in this format is being passed as an input to the program. I am trying to read them using `scanf()` but to no avail.

Some of the formats that I have tried are

`scanf("%[^@]s%f",&s,&f);`

`scanf("%s@%f",&s,&f);`

`scanf("%s[@]%f",&s,&f);`

No matter what I give the whole value (the string with the @ symbol and the float value) is being stored in the s itself.

In a previous post I saw someone using this `%4[^\n]`which can be used to read 4 inputs or until a new line is encountered. Unfortunately the input size is not known to me. I tried a workaround using `getchar()` function. In that too after reaching '@' symbol I am using `scanf("%f",&f)` to read the input, which is throwing me segmentation error. How can I solve this?

Comment: You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: The `[ ]` is a format specifier on its own, not a modifier for `s`, and you're missing the closing quote character.... so `scanf("%[^@]@%f",s,&f);`

Comment: You may also want a space at the beginning of the format string if you need to skip leading whitespace, and give a maximum width before the `[` so you don't overrun your string buffer, and check the return value to make sure both fields were successfully assigned.

Comment: Show declaration of `s`

Comment: I would find the `@` with a pointer, then convert remainder of string to float, and use the earlier part in-place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove an `&` before `s`, this should work:

```
scanf("%[^@]@%f",s,&f);
```

Comment: This answer is working..But can someone give me explanation of why my original code is not working and this does?